# Not able to clear the partial swipe delete button after swipe back in recycler view android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout, itemtouchhelper

I am trying to create archive like swipe action of gmail in my app.

I am able to draw the image and text while sliding.But the problem is after the slide back the delete button image is not removed.

How to remove the delete button after slide back.I don't know what i'm doing wrong with my code.

```
class SwipeController extends Callback {

    private Paint p = new Paint();
    private Context context;
    public SwipeController(Context context) {
          this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        return makeMovementFlags(0, LEFT);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int convertToAbsoluteDirection(int flags, int layoutDirection) {
        Log.d("convertToDirection","convertToAbsoluteDirection Executed");
        return super.convertToAbsoluteDirection(flags, layoutDirection);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

        if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT){
            //adapter.removeItem(position);remove item from adapter
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

        Bitmap icon;
        if(actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE){

            View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
            float height = (float) itemView.getBottom() - (float) itemView.getTop();
            float width = height / 3;


            try{
                if(dX > 0){
                    p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#388E3C"));
                    RectF background = new RectF((float) itemView.getLeft(), (float) itemView.getTop(), dX,(float) itemView.getBottom());
                    c.drawRect(background,p);
                    icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.voicemaildelte);
                    RectF icon_dest = new RectF((float) itemView.getLeft() + width ,(float) itemView.getTop() + width,(float) itemView.getLeft()+ 2*width,(float)itemView.getBottom() - width);
                    c.drawBitmap(icon,null,icon_dest,p);
                } else {
                    p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#D32F2F"));
                    RectF background = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() + dX, (float) itemView.getTop(),(float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom());
                    c.drawRect(background,p);
                    icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.voicemaildelte);
                    RectF icon_dest = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() - 2*width ,(float) itemView.getTop() + width,(float) itemView.getRight() - width,(float)itemView.getBottom() - width);
                    c.drawBitmap(icon,null,icon_dest,p);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }


}
```

[[image: delete button not removed][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7wLg.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a way to redraw them.

**isCurrentlyActive** this variable indicates whether the viewholder is currently under the control of user it returns true so used it to  draw the buttons only when the viewholder is being swiped by the user.

```
@Override
public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

    Bitmap icon;
    if(actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE && isCurrentlyActive){

        View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
        float height = (float) itemView.getBottom() - (float) itemView.getTop();
        float width = height / 3;


        try{
            if(dX > 0){
                p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#388E3C"));
                RectF background = new RectF((float) itemView.getLeft(), (float) itemView.getTop(), dX,(float) itemView.getBottom());
                c.drawRect(background,p);
                icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.voicemaildelte);
                RectF icon_dest = new RectF((float) itemView.getLeft() + width ,(float) itemView.getTop() + width,(float) itemView.getLeft()+ 2*width,(float)itemView.getBottom() - width);
                c.drawBitmap(icon,null,icon_dest,p);
            } else {
                p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#D32F2F"));
                RectF background = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() + dX, (float) itemView.getTop(),(float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom());
                c.drawRect(background,p);
                icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.voicemaildelte);
                RectF icon_dest = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() - 2*width ,(float) itemView.getTop() + width,(float) itemView.getRight() - width,(float)itemView.getBottom() - width);
                c.drawBitmap(icon,null,icon_dest,p);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
}
```